# Creating a nested list from an imported single column file

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I am wanting to open a text file where the first line gives the number of rows in the grid and the second line gives the number of columns.  All values after that should be added to the nested list one row at a time.  Not sure how to do this, any help is appreciated!

```
    with open(filename, 'r') as gridFile:
        grid = []
        for line in gridFile:
            if line == 0:
                rows = int(line)
            if line == 1:
                col = int(line)
            else:
                # add the values row by row
```

Comment: why not create a list of tuples? would that suffice? for example, the `grid` list would look like this: `[(row1, col1), (row2, col2)...]`

Comment: @sagar1025 I feel like that would definitely be easier but I am supposed to use a nested list for it /:

Comment: when you read a file, you will have end of line. you need to strip that out first. Then use the rest of the information. Also all data read from a file will be in string format. You need to convert it to a number first (using say int()) otherwise, you need to check for `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as gridFile:
    lines = gridFile.readlines()
    rows = int(lines[0])
    cols = int(lines[1])
    
    grid = [[None for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]
    cursor_row, cursor_col = 0, 0

    for line in lines[2:]:
        grid[cursor_row][cursor_col] = line.strip()
        if cursor_col + 1 < cols:
            cursor_col += 1
        else:
            if cursor_row + 1 < rows:
                cursor_row += 1
                cursor_col = 0
            else:
                raise IndexError
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use enumerate to find the line number you are reading.

Use this to process the first few lines.

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as gridFile:
    grid = []
    for i, line in enumerate(gridFile):
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if i == 0:
            rows = int(line)
        elif i == 1:
            col = int(line)
        else:
            grid.append(line)
            # add the values row by row

print (rows, col, grid)
```

Here's the input file data I had:

```
8
2
Good,Morning
Happy,Friday
Python,Programming
```

Here's the output it printed out:

```
8 2 ['Good,Morning', 'Happy,Friday', 'Python,Programming']
```

Now that you know how many rows and columns the file will have, you can expand the above program to store the right number of rows and columns.

The best part is that python can do that for you without you needing to figure it out. If the data is comma separated, you can just use split(',') to split them into columns.

For example, changing the last line to

```
grid.append(line.split(','))
```

your output will be different for `grid`.

Instead of giving you a list like this:

```
['Good,Morning', 'Happy,Friday', 'Python,Programming']
```

It will give you a list like this (list of lists with two values (or 2 columns) in each 'row' of the list:

```
[['Good', 'Morning'], ['Happy', 'Friday'], ['Python', 'Programming']]
```